# Knockout JS Json get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, knockout.js

I am a newbie at `knockout.js` and I have a question. I found some code [here](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/%23/?tutorial=intro). My get function returns `{"id":"1", "name":"cardio", "image":"aslas", "header":"Kardio", "message":"message\r\n"}` but it is not working. Can anyone help me? Thanks

```
         <ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
    <li data-bind="text: $data,
               css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() },
               click: $root.goToFolder"></li>
</ul>
<div class="mails" data-bind="with: chosenFolderData">
    <p><label>From</label>: <span data-bind="text: name"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
    function WebmailViewModel() {
        // Data
        var self = this;

        self.folders = ['cardio', 'classic', 'mass', 'abs']

        ;
        self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
        self.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();
        self.chosenMailData = ko.observable();
        // Behaviours
        self.goToFolder = function(folder) {
            self.chosenFolderId(folder);
            self.chosenMailData(null);
            $.get(ajax_url+'Dieticians/video/'+folder,null, self.chosenFolderData);
        };
        self.goToFolder('Inbox');

    };

    ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
</script>
```

Comment: looks working for me check here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/23414/ . if you looking for something in particular let us know , cheers

Comment: try this the above fiddle looks broken with spell mistake . http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/23416/

Comment: when you click  folders button ,it get json from server and write it in span? @supercool

Comment: yes all you need to do is just have ajax call which gets your data dynamically and push into `self.chosenFolderData` .

Comment: Yes u right;    self.chosenFolderData({'name':folder}); << its work but i need this>> $.get(ajax_url+'Dieticians/video/'+folder,null, self.chosenFolderData); and it returns "{"id":"1","name":"cardio","image":"aslmk\u015fga\u015fgkl","header":"Kardio","message":"message text"}" . But not write anything in span. @supercool

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?: http://jsfiddle.net/58tkrbd9/3/

```
<ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
        <li data-bind="text: $data,
                   css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() },
                   click: $root.goToFolder"></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <div class="mails" data-bind="with: chosenFolderData">
        <p><label>From</label>: <span data-bind="text: name"></span></p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function WebmailViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            self.folders = ko.observableArray(['cardio', 'classic', 'mass', 'abs']);
            self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
            self.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();
            self.chosenMailData = ko.observable();
            // Behaviours
            self.goToFolder = function(folder) {
                console.log(folder);
                self.chosenFolderId(folder);
                self.chosenMailData(null);
                //apply you ajax call and fill 'chosenFolderData' 
                self.chosenFolderData({"id":"1", "name":"cardio", "image":"aslas", "header":"Kardio", "message":"message\r\n"});  
            };
            self.goToFolder('Inbox');
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes it is work but when i use :  $.get(ajax_url+'Dieticians/video/'+folder,null, self.chosenFolderData); it is not working . @Kelvin17

Comment: $.ajax({
                        url:ajax_url+'Dieticians/video/'+folder,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success:function(data) {
                            self.chosenFolderData(data);
                        }
                        });   <<< it's work :(

Comment: You have chosenFolderData as an observable if you want to set its value you have to say like this
    self.chosenFolderData( [valueyouwant] )

That inside an anonimous function that you create on succes of ajax request, look: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
Hope this helps